# How to reference a class object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

Assume the following class:

```
class Player{
 constructor(id,name){
  this.id=id;
  this.name=name;
 }
}
```

If I would like to instantiate the class I would go about `var player = new Player(1,'Mike')` and then I could access the values with dot notation such as `player.name`. I'm trying to use an iteration to generate several players and add them into an array and part of the code is:

```
let player =[];
player.push( playerName = new Player(id,playerName));
```

If insert a var infront of playerName i.e. `player.push( playerName = new Player(id,playerName);` it throws an error. Currently the only way to access the name would be `player[0].name` which is not convenient. How else could I make the code so as to create an Object variable as in the example above?

Comment: try player.push(new Player(id, playerName)); You are missing the closing parenthesis too

Comment: You are missing `)`? -- `player.push(  new Player(id,playerName) );`

Comment: I'd highly recommend not using the same variable name only with different casing - use something at least a bit different, such as `players` to represent an array of players, to ensure it doesn't get mixed up with the class itself.

Comment: it's now the same variable, I'm calling a function and the playerName is changing. But I can't reference it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I personally can deal with the initial capital for Class v.s. no initial capital for instance distinction, but I remember not being able to. Some people find this harder than others, so it's best to create readable as opposed to write-only code.

Comment: Please post your complete code. If you want to create an array of players, there really is no reason why you would want to have a specific player object available in an extra variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two separate statements. It makes the code clearer.

```
let player_list = [];
for (some ... loop) {
   let some_player = new Player(id,playerName);
   player_list.push(some_player);
   do_something_else_with(some_player);
}
```

Comment: this won't work as it throws the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'playerName' has already been declared`

Comment: @Kleo — What error, you failed to include it. (I hope you aren't referring to the obvious placeholder of `some ... loop` that you are expected to replace with a real loop condition).

Comment: @Kleo — It doesn't … it doesn't declare `playerName` at all. You must have modified it somehow.

Comment: @Kleo The code in the answer is only an example. It doesn't even define `playerName`. The error suggests the full code declares `playerName` more than once. If you're trying this out in some console, it's a common mistake.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to that. Part of the code will be a for loop and in another case would be a function call. Here is the code

Comment: @Kleo Please add the relevant of your code in the question. Adding new information in comments is a not a good practice at all.

Comment: I know, apologies for that but I thought it would have been an easy fix. I have added above the link

Comment: @Kleo — You're trying to assign a value to `playerName` at about the same time as you are trying to read from `playerName`. It's a chicken and egg situation. It doesn't make sense. don't do that. If you know the name, then you don't need to get the name. `playerName` means two different things on the same line, then use two different variable names that properly describe the different meanings.

Comment: @Quentin, it still doesn't make any difference if I insert 2 different variables. Still throws the same error which is which is the playerName variable has already been defined.